# How can I configure eslint to enforce Haskell/Elm record style for objects in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, haskell, eslint, elm

I'm finally working on a Javascript project in which I can dictate the coding style, and I would like to use Haskell/Elm records style for objects, that is:

```js
const imAnObject =
    { key1: "Value"
    , key2: 1337
    , obj:
      { hi: "I'm an object!"
      }
    , arr:
      [ "This
      , "is an"
      , "array"
      ]
    }
```

I've managed to configure the space after comma, and commas on start of new line, but I want to configure also `[{` to start on new line (preferably only on long lines) and space after them, and the whole aligning thing. Any ideas on how to achieve that? Eslint has a lot of options and they are not as searchable as I would have wished for.

Comment: Make sure you are not enforcing it for object returned inside a function `return /**new line*/ {` as it will return `undefined`